# Localstorage doesn't "save" + displaying in HTML.

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

So I have this script which puts stuff in an array and strings it to put it in to localstorage. But for some reason it forgets the string and the localstorage is reset when I revisit the website.

Here's the script:

```
var favorites = [];
$(document).on('click', '#favoriteadd', function() {
favorites.push($('h5').text());
localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
});
```

Also I cannot find a way to get this to get this back to my HTML. Any tips? Cheers

Comment: Which Browser are you using?

Comment: Can you post a small example on http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first test the storage available, because lot of browser dont allow it.

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And look up for the browser compatility in books, like
[here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

And try to mixing up with sessions & cookies like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)